# Syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '(' in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have done some googling on this error I have an it seems to be an error in the blade templates but I cannot see what I have done that is different to my other templates that work. This is the error message

```
FatalErrorException in 66e07bb82defb1810fc6e13b82dc623493bf38fa.php line 11:
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('
```

This is the line of code in the file that I have not touched that is showing as an error in my IDE

```
<?php if: ?>
```

and finally here is my view that triggers the error message when I submit the form.

```
    @extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h3>Your Account</h3>
            <form action="{{ route('profile.avatar') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="image">Image (only .jpg)</label>
                    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" id="image">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Account</button>
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ Session::token() }}" name="_token">
            </form>
</div>
@stop
```

templates.default

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        @include('templates.partials.navigation')
        <div class="container">
            @include('templates.partials.alerts')
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if` what? I think blade templates are expecting `@if(condition)` and `@endif` later on

Comment: @acm Hmm thanks that makes sense, I had not got that far yet was just trying to check if the upload worked. I'll try to add the conditions in now

Comment: The code triggering this error is not shown in your excerpt... I think it's located inside templates.default

Comment: @shock_gone_wild just updating the question and adding the default template file contents. It works fine when I include the templates.default in other views though

Comment: can u  remove the @include('templates.partials.navigation') and try ? tell me if the probleme still exists (try that for the other one 2 )

Comment: and try to use this {!! csrf_field() !!} instead of {{ Session::token() }}

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Thanks for the help, you made me realise that the error was coming from a view that my Controller redirects me to after uploading the image. I have now fixed it

Comment: Good for you :3 Dont forget to delete/ or answer ur question so  people will know that you found the solution

Answer (score 6):

Forgetting to type the complete syntax expected by the directives of laravel blade template control structures can cause this. For instance the following will produce the same error that the OP came across:

```
@if (count($data) == 0)
    //do something
@elseif
    //do something else
@endif
```

while the following code does not:

```
@if (count($data) == 0)
    //do something
@else
    //do something else
@endif
```

The `@elseif` part expects a condition to evaluate and upon finding nothing the blade template parser goes bonkers.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use anything like `<?php if: ?>`. If you want to use conditions inside Blade templates, do something like this:

```
@if($a == 2)
    A is 2
@endif
```

[Read here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures) for more information.

Comment: I wasn't using those conditions I currently have no conditions in my view but the <?php if: ?> are in a Laravel generated file located in storage\framework\views\66e07bb82defb1810fc6e13b82dc623493bf38fa.php line 11

Comment: Run `php artisan view:clear` to clear all views cache.

Answer (score 0):

The function that was being called was redirecting me to another view that I had not checked, when I realised it was redirecting me upon submitting the form I then checked the view and it had a stray @if in it which was causing the error.